# JAVA regex to contain words with dot in the middle of letters and contain special words with dot

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 problems. First 1) is how do I contain words with dot between two letters, like "C.J Johnson" and 2nd 2) is that is it possible to make list of words that contains dot and my regex would include them? Basically I want to search text file with word(s) and list all sentences containing those word(s). My code:

```
public void search_sentences() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //FileReader fr1 = new FileReader(get_File());
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(get_File()),  "UTF-8"));
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("rivit.txt", "UTF-8");
        String str="";
        //String [] words = {};
        String sanat = get_Text();
        for(String w: sanat.split(", ")){
            words.add(w);
        }
        String word_re = words.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < words.size(); i++)
                word_re += "|" + words.get(i);
            word_re = "[^.!?]*\\b(" + word_re + ")\\b[^.!?]*[.!?]";
            while(br1.ready()) { str += br1.readLine(); }
            Pattern re = Pattern.compile(word_re, 
                    Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS | 
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher match = re.matcher(str);
            String sentenceString="";
            while (match .find()) {
                sentenceString = match.group(0);
                if(!txtFile.isSelected()){
                tekstiAlue.append(sentenceString);
                } else {
                    writer.println(sentenceString);
                }

            }
        writer.close();

    }
```

The first question is doable, I think. Ive tried adding //s to different positions in the

`"[^.!?]*\\b(" + word_re + ")\\b[^.!?]*[.!?]"`

The second one I am not sure at all. Example for the 2nd:
My txt file contains sentence "Today was fun day, for exmpl. we played football" and I search with keyword "fun". Now it should return the whole sentence including "exmpl." because I have listed that word to some list before. Is it possible?

*EDIT*
For the second question, I tried to:
1. Add the special words to list and escape the dot after them
`String [] saanat ={"esim\\.","yms\\.","jne\\.","tms\\.","etc\\."};` 
2. Append the word_re with the spec words including dots
`for(String x : saanat)
    word_re += "|" + x;`

And it didnt do the deed. Ideas?

Comment: Look at Pattern.quote().

Comment: Outside a `[...]` character class, `.` period has special meaning, so you need to ``\`` escape it: ``\.`` --- If you know enough regex to write things like `[^.!?]` and ``\\b``, how can you not know this?

Comment: I modified my code for the 2nd part and now my original word_re is "keyword | keyword2 |specword1\.|specword2\. "
but it still cuts the search on the dot of keyword. And yes I use \\, not just \ when escaping the dot in the strings. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff Holt said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61331838/java-regex-to-contain-words-with-dot-in-the-middle-of-letters-and-contain-specia?noredirect=1#comment108499335_61331838), "Look at [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)":

> [...] produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

The regex in the question uses `[^.!?]*` to match any character in a sentence that is not a sentence-ending character (`.`, `!`, or `?`).

However we want to match full sentences with special "words" like `i.e.`, `e.g.` and `etc.`, so we need to enhance that to `(i.e.|e.g.|etc.|[^.!?])*`, except we have to escape (`\`) the regex special characters (like `.`) in those special words.

We can use `Pattern.quote()` for that, as well as for the search word itself.

```
public static List<String> findSentencesContaining(String fullText, String word, String[] specials) {
    Pattern p = buildRegexToFindSentencesContaining(word, specials);
    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Matcher m = p.matcher(fullText); m.find(); )
        sentences.add(m.group().replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim()); // normalize group of whitespace into a single space
    return sentences;
}
public static Pattern buildRegexToFindSentencesContaining(String word, String[] specials) {
    StringJoiner regexText = new StringJoiner("|", "(?:", "|[^.!?])*").setEmptyValue("[^.!?]*");
    for (String s : specials)
        regexText.add(toWordRegex(s));
    String regex = regexText + toWordRegex(word) + regexText + "[.!?]";
    return Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
}
private static String toWordRegex(String word) {
    String regex = Pattern.quote(word);
    if (word.matches("\\b.*"))
        regex = "\\b" + regex;
    if (word.matches(".*\\b"))
        regex = regex + "\\b";
    return regex;
}
```

*Test*

```
String fullText = "This is a test. We're testing that sentences\n" +
                  "can span multiple lines, i.e. that line" +
                  "terminators can appear in a sentence. We're\n" +
                  "also testing that sentences can contain\n" +
                  "special words containing sentence-ending\n" +
                  "\"words\", e.g. \"i.e.\" and \"etc.\". In\n" +
                  "addition, (special) word matching is\n" +
                  "case-insensitive.";
String[] specials = { "i.e.", "e.g.", "etc." };
for (String word : new String[] { "test", "also", "we're", "is", "happy" }) {
    System.out.println("Sentences containing word \"" + word + "\":");
    List<String> sentences = findSentencesContaining(fullText, word, specials);
    if (sentences.isEmpty())
        System.out.println("  ** NOT FOUND");
    else {
        for (String sentence : sentences)
            System.out.println("  " + sentence);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Sentences containing word "test":
  This is a test.
Sentences containing word "also":
  We're also testing that sentences can contain special words containing sentence-ending "words", e.g. "i.e." and "etc.".
Sentences containing word "we're":
  We're testing that sentences can span multiple lines, i.e. that lineterminators can appear in a sentence.
  We're also testing that sentences can contain special words containing sentence-ending "words", e.g. "i.e." and "etc.".
Sentences containing word "is":
  This is a test.
  In addition, (special) word matching is case-insensitive.
Sentences containing word "happy":
  ** NOT FOUND
```